# Why Class CloneNotSupportedException is a checked Exception and does not extend RuntimeException instead?

Tags: java

How can the caller of `clone()` possibly recover if they encounter a  CloneNotSupportedException ? Why is it a checked Exception ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is it a checked Exception?

I suspect the answer is really: "because when Java first came out, there was very little experience of when it would make sense for an exception to be checked." Back then, they didn't have Effective Java :)

There are various things like this - exceptions which are checked but probably shouldn't be, and occasions where the exception is unchecked but should be checked... `Integer.parseInt` throwing `NumberFormatException` probably being the clearest example.

Comment: What is your take for `IOException` to be a checked exception ? Shouldn't it also have been an unchecked exception ?

Comment: We can only bless every circumstance where they "mistakenly" made an exception unchecked :)